# Laravel: does the length of the route file api.php has any negative influence in performance?

Tags: php, laravel

I recently noticed that my `api.php` route file has 500kb length, compared to `web.php` which has 30kb. I have more than 100 API endpoints & the API is public.

In every single API endpoint I use the same structure:

```
try 
{
    // Do something
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
    \Log::critical($e->getMessage());

    return response()->json(['message' => 'Unexpected error..'], 403);
}
```

None of the endpoints points to a controller, only few endpoints points to a class & returns a value.

A common full example of and endpoint content:

```
try 
{
    // Validates if allowed
    if (UserIsNotAllowed(....))
        return response()->json(['message' => "You don't have rights to access this endpoint"], 403);

    // Applies validations
    $data = ['description' => $request->description];
    $rules =
    [
        'description' =>
        [
            'required',
            Rule::unique('some_table_sample', 'description')->where(function($query)
            {
                $query->where('subscription_id', \Auth::user()->subscription_id);
            })
        ],
    ];

    $validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);

    if ($validator->fails())
        return response()->json(['message' => $validator->errors()->first()], 403);

    // Adds to table
    $sts = new \App\Models\SomeTableSample;
    $sts->subscription_id = \Auth::user()->subscription_id;
    $sts->description = $request->description;
    $sts->active = $request->active == 'true';
    $sts->save();

    // Log in DB 
    (new \App\Classes\Log)->setSubscription(...)
        ->setUser('...')
        ->setTableId('...')
        ->setTableName('...')
        ->setAction('Created')
        ->create();

    return response()->json(['data' => $sts], 200);
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
    \Log::critical($e->getMessage());

    return response()->json(['message' => 'Unexpected error..'], 403);
}
```

I'm not saying I have noticed any performance issue, but I was wondering if this may lead in the future to some troubles? Should I start thinking about moving all the content of the endpoints towards a controller?

Comment: Amount of code _shouldn't_ make a difference, but it can. What would effect performance is complexity; a single line of code _can_ be infinitely more complex than many lines of code, depending on what it is responsible for. For organization, you _should_ have this code in Controllers, but it's not a hard requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ease of maintenance it would be worth refactoring. For your future self and other developers, having a well-organised routing/processing architecture will help keep development moving.

As for performance: it likely will, though I'm unsure at what point Laravel will start to slow. Worth doing some profiling as you refactor.